# WPF DependencyProperty Exposing in UserControl?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, argument-passing

I have a UserControl where I'd like to have some parameters of customization "radius"(double) and "contentSource" (string[]).

My UserControl is composed of a few nested controls:

```
<UserControl ...>
<Grid>
    <my:Menu ...>
        <my:Button>
        </my:Button>
        <my:Button>
        </my:Button>
        <my:Button>
        </my:Button>
    </my:Menu ...>
</Grid>
```

I'm trying to expose the parameters with:

```
    public double Rad
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(RadProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RadProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RadProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Radius",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(Menu));

    public String[] DataSource
    {
        get { return (String[])GetValue(DataSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataSourceProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "DataSource",
            typeof(String[]),
            typeof(Menu));
```

However, there seems to be two problems, the "string[]" parameter seems to be causing crashes, but mostly, I cannot set the "Radius" property at all. Is there something else I need to do to expose the parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you trying to access the values?  I have copied your code into a UserControl and it seems to work fine.  Have you set the DataContext for the object you are accessing these values from?

Here is my test code, which might help:

```
 public partial class uc : UserControl
{
    public uc()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = this;
        this.DataSource = new string[] { "hello","There" };
        this.Rad = 7;
    }
    public String[] DataSource
    {
        get { return (String[])GetValue(DataSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataSourceProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "DataSource",
            typeof(String[]),
            typeof(uc));

    public double Rad
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(RadProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RadProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RadProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Radius",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(uc));

}
```

and the XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication18.uc"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=DataSource[0]}"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=DataSource[1]}"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Radius}"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Radius}"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: this looks good, there's some stuff I didn't know, however I'm using my UserControl in a different class, and doing something like:
<my:UserControl Radius=2 />
Could I do something like that?

Comment: Yep, but you need to use the name of the public property, which is "Rad".  This will work:    <Grid>
        <local:uc Rad="15"></local:uc>
    </Grid>

Comment: ah, i've now found that my issue is that the values are not yet set when we are in the CustomControl's constructor. is there somewhere where the the control is not yet displayed when i could read the value that has been set?

Comment: The control is instantiated and then its properties are assigned, so your constructor isn't the right place for anything that depends on property values. Try the Loaded event (you can hook it in your constructor, but then delay your logic until the event fires).